# How to get Arduino Robot token?

Tags: arduino, robotics

[image]Yesterday I built a robot called **Miro**. I want to use Open Roberta but I have to connect the robot using a token, but I don't know how to get that token.
**note**: I'm using Windows 10 enterprise as my os.

[image]

I really need some help with that.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

When I go to https://lab.open-roberta.org/ the very first thing I see is a pop-up that says:

> Would you like to get started, but do not know exactly how? We will
> show you the first steps in an interactive tutorial.

I've never used this service, but I would think that would be the place to start.